# Eclipse Install Plugin on Initial Installation

Tags: eclipse, bash, macos, shell, eclipse-plugin

I am attempting to make a script to automatically install Eclipse and with it a plugin *wpilib*. However, executing

```
~/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -clean -data $HOME/eclipse-workspace/ -purgeHistory -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://first.wpi.edu/FRC/roborio/release/eclipse/ -installIUs edu.wpi.first.wpilib.plugins.java.feature.feature.group
```

on MacOS High Sierra results in

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Installing edu.wpi.first.wpilib.plugins.java.feature.feature.group 2017.3.1.
Operation completed in 1767 ms.
```

and no installation of the plugin. Strangely, once Eclipse is opened and a workspace is selected, the script can then be executed successfully: (note I still get a warning)

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Installing edu.wpi.first.wpilib.plugins.java.feature.feature.group 2017.3.1.
Operation completed in 2194 ms.
```

I am speculating that the error is caused by not all Eclipse dependencies being installed until the workspace is selected. Is there anyway I can do this in the command line and without a GUI?

**Full code**

```
curl "http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/eclipse/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/1a/eclipse-java-oxygen-1a-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg" -o /tmp/TeamWikiInstallation/eclipse.dmg
echo '> Attaching'
hdiutil attach -quiet /tmp/TeamWikiInstallation/eclipse.dmg

echo '> Copying'
cp -R '/Volumes/Eclipse/Eclipse.app' ~/Applications/

echo '> Detaching'
ECLIPSE_DRIVE="$(diskutil info '/Volumes/Eclipse/' | awk '/Device Node/ {print $3}')"
hdiutil detach -quiet $ECLIPSE_DRIVE
~/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -clean -data $HOME/eclipse-workspace/ -purgeHistory -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://first.wpi.edu/FRC/roborio/release/eclipse/ -installIUs edu.wpi.first.wpilib.plugins.java.feature.feature.group
```